# Have to format HDFS repeatedly whenever I stop and start hadoop services

Tags: hadoop

I setup hadoop on a single node cluster. Everything works fine when I start all the hadoop services using start=all.sh. However whenever I stop all the services and restart hadoop services I get the following exception and I have to reformat the file system again. Right now I am in development and I am copying the files whenever I reformat it. But I cannot afford to have this kind of behaviour in production. I have checked the logs and here is the exception. Also my etc/hosts file is the same and I disabled IPV6

```
2012-11-03 18:49:45,542 INFO     org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode:             STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = nikhil-VirtualBox/127.0.1.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.0.4
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches    /branch-1.0 -r 1393290; compiled by 'hortonfo' on Wed Oct  3 05:13:58 UTC 2012
************************************************************/
2012-11-03 18:49:45,738 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2012-11-03 18:49:45,750 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2012-11-03 18:49:45,751 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2012-11-03 18:49:45,751 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system started
2012-11-03 18:49:45,899 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2012-11-03 18:49:45,902 WARN org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Source name ugi already exists!
2012-11-03 18:49:45,910 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source jvm registered.
2012-11-03 18:49:45,910 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source NameNode registered.
2012-11-03 18:49:45,932 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: VM type       = 32-bit
2012-11-03 18:49:45,934 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: 2% max memory = 19.33375 MB
2012-11-03 18:49:45,934 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^22 = 4194304 entries
2012-11-03 18:49:45,934 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: recommended=4194304, actual=4194304
2012-11-03 18:49:46,020 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner=hduser
2012-11-03 18:49:46,020 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup=supergroup
2012-11-03 18:49:46,021 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled=true
2012-11-03 18:49:46,024 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=100
2012-11-03 18:49:46,024 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isAccessTokenEnabled=false accessKeyUpdateInterval=0 min(s), accessTokenLifetime=0 min(s)
2012-11-03 18:49:46,169 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Registered FSNamesystemStateMBean and NameNodeMXBean
2012-11-03 18:49:46,191 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times 
2012-11-03 18:49:46,194 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Storage directory /tmp/hadoop-hduser/dfs/name does not exist.
2012-11-03 18:49:46,196 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: FSNamesystem initialization failed.
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory     /tmp/hadoop-hduser/dfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist     or is not accessible.
at             org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:303)
at     org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:100)
at     org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:388)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:362)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:276)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:496)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1279)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1288)
2012-11-03 18:49:46,197 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /tmp/hadoop-hduser/dfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:303)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:100)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:388)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:362)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:276)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:496)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1279)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1288)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply don't install your HDFS inside the `/tmp` directory. It will be cleaned up by your OS everytime you boot.

Personally I have installed my HDFS in `/srv/hdfs/`, but that is a matter of taste I guess.

Comment: Thank you. That help me understand why I was having this issue.

Comment: See this answer for more details on how to change config: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38100392/3757139