# Why do we need to format HDFS after every time we restart machine?

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-11.04

I have installed Hadoop in pseudo distributed mode on my laptop, OS is Ubuntu.

I have changed paths where hadoop will store its data (by default hadoop stores data in `/tmp` folder)

`hdfs-site.xml` file looks as below :

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
    <value>/HADOOP_CLUSTER_DATA/data</value>
</property>
```

Now whenever I restart machine and try to start hadoop cluster using `start-all.sh` script, data node never starts. I confirmed that data node is not start by checking logs and by using `jps` command.

Then I

1. Stopped cluster using `stop-all.sh` script.
2. Formatted HDFS using `hadoop namenode -format` command.
3. Started cluster using `start-all.sh` script.

Now everything works fine even if I stop and start cluster again. Problem occurs only when I restart machine and try to start the cluster.

- Has anyone encountered similar problem?
- Why this is happening and
- How can we solve this problem?

Comment: which is your default location now?

Comment: @sonic, I have modified my question as per your comment.

Comment: You have the answer below :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By changing [`dfs.datanode.data.dir`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml) away from `/tmp` you indeed made the data (the blocks) survive across a reboot. However there is more to HDFS than just blocks. You need to make sure all the relevant dirs point away from `/tmp`, most notably `dfs.namenode.name.dir` (I can't tell what other dirs you have to change, it depends on your config, but the namenode dir is mandatory, could be also sufficient).

I would also recommend using a more recent Hadoop distribution. BTW, the 1.1 namenode dir setting is [`dfs.name.dir`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/hdfs-default.html).

Answer (score 4):

For those who use hadoop 2.0 or above versions config file names may be different.

As this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23745585/3757139) points out, go to the `/etc/hadoop` directory of your hadoop installation.

Open the file **hdfs-site.xml**. This [user configuration will override the default hadoop configurations](http://grokbase.com/t/cloudera/cdh-user/12agx0wj8y/where-can-i-find-the-core-default-and-hdfs-default-xml-file), that are loaded by the java classloader before.

Add [`dfs.namenode.name.dir`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml) property and set a new namenode dir (default is `file://${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/name`).

Do the same for `dfs.datanode.data.dir` property (default is `file://${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/data`).

For example:

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>/Users/samuel/Documents/hadoop_data/name</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>/Users/samuel/Documents/hadoop_data/data</value>
</property>
```

Other property where a tmp dir appears is `dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir`. Its default value is: `file://${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/namesecondary`.

If you want, you can easily also add this property:

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir</name>
    <value>/Users/samuel/Documents/hadoop_data/namesecondary</value>
</property>
```

Comment: After doing this, don't forget to format your file system, like: `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs namenode -format`. Replace $HADOOP_HOME environment variable with your absolute path to hadoop, if var is not set.