# Can't find the conf directory in Hadoop

Tags: apache, hadoop, amazon-ec2

I'd like to install Hadoop on an EC2 instance running Ubuntu 16.04 (for learning purposes). I'm trying to follow the instructions on https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/single_node_setup.html. I'm at the step

> In the distribution, edit the file `conf/hadoop-env.sh` to define at least `JAVA_HOME` to be the root of your Java installation.

I've downloaded the 3.0.0-beta1 version as a binary (using `wget http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/common/hadoop-3.0.0-beta1/hadoop-3.0.0-beta1.tar.gz` followed by a `tar xzf` of that file). However, I don't see any `conf` directory in the directory thus extracted:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-83-170:~/hadoop-3.0.0-beta1$ ls
bin  include  libexec      NOTICE.txt  sbin
etc  lib      LICENSE.txt  README.txt  share
```

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that this question is answered in [Hadoop release missing /conf directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22496421/hadoop-release-missing-conf-directory). The place to look is `/etc/hadoop`:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-83-170:~/hadoop-3.0.0-beta1/etc/hadoop$ ls
capacity-scheduler.xml            kms-log4j.properties
configuration.xsl                 kms-site.xml
container-executor.cfg            log4j.properties
core-site.xml                     mapred-env.cmd
hadoop-env.cmd                    mapred-env.sh
hadoop-env.sh                     mapred-queues.xml.template
hadoop-metrics2.properties        mapred-site.xml
hadoop-policy.xml                 shellprofile.d
hadoop-user-functions.sh.example  ssl-client.xml.example
hdfs-site.xml                     ssl-server.xml.example
httpfs-env.sh                     user_ec_policies.xml.template
httpfs-log4j.properties           workers
httpfs-signature.secret           yarn-env.cmd
httpfs-site.xml                   yarn-env.sh
kms-acls.xml                      yarn-site.xml
kms-env.sh
```

This contains the `hadoop-env.sh` file referred to in the instructions.

Comment: You should also use the Single Node Setup from the same release.  http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.0-beta1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html

Answer (score 0):

The configuration folder is in your ${HADOOP_HOME}/etc/hadoop

Where ${HADOOP_HOME} is your hadoop installation directory